# Google Fit : Cannot update both step and distance in real-time

Tags: java, android, google-fit

I can use sensor api to get step data in real time.
I also can get distance data in real time too.
However, I can't get step and distance together.

### This is my code.

```
private void registerFitnessDataListener(final DataSource dataSource, final DataType dataType) {
    if (mListener == null)
        mListener = new OnDataPointListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataPoint(DataPoint dataPoint) {
                isUpdatingStep = false;
                if (!isUpdatingStep) {
                    for (Field field : dataPoint.getDataType().getFields()) {
                        if (String.valueOf(field).equals("steps(i)")) {
                            thisActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    if (!isUpdatingStep) {
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                        } else if (String.valueOf(field).equals("distance(f)")) {
                            thisActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    if (!isUpdatingStep) {
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        };
    SensorRequest req = new SensorRequest.Builder()
            .setDataSource(dataSource)
            .setDataType(dataType)
            .setSamplingRate(2000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .build();

    Fitness.SensorsApi.add(
            mClient,
            req,
            mListener)
            .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(Status status) {
                    if (status.isSuccess()) {
                    } else {
                    }
                }
            });
}

   private void findFitnessDataSources(final DataType dataType) {
    Fitness.SensorsApi.findDataSources(mClient, new DataSourcesRequest.Builder()
            .setDataTypes(dataType)
            .setDataSourceTypes(DataSource.TYPE_DERIVED)
            .build())
            .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<DataSourcesResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(DataSourcesResult dataSourcesResult) {
                    for (DataSource dataSource : dataSourcesResult.getDataSources()) {
                        if (dataSource.getDataType().equals(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA)) {
                            registerFitnessDataListener(dataSource, DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA);
                            setDailySteps();
                        } else if (dataSource.getDataType().equals(DataType.TYPE_DISTANCE_DELTA)) {
                            registerFitnessDataListener(dataSource, DataType.TYPE_DISTANCE_DELTA);
                            setDailyDistance();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
}

    private void buildFitnessClient() {
    if (mClient == null && checkPermissions()) {
        mClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
                .addApi(Fitness.SENSORS_API)
                .addApi(Fitness.HISTORY_API)
                .addScope(Fitness.SCOPE_ACTIVITY_READ)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(
                        new GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks() {
                            @Override
                            public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
                                findFitnessDataSources(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA);
                                findFitnessDataSources(DataType.TYPE_DISTANCE_DELTA);
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
                                if (i == GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks.CAUSE_NETWORK_LOST) {
                                } else if (i == GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks.CAUSE_SERVICE_DISCONNECTED) {
                                }
                            }
                        }
                )
                .enableAutoManage(getActivity(), 0, new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
                    }
                })
                .build();
    }
}
```

Ps. when I comment one of these functions. `findFitnessDataSources(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA);` or `findFitnessDataSources(DataType.TYPE_DISTANCE_DELTA);`

in method `buildFitnessClient()`.

The app can work properly.(Update only a single value)

Comment: Which intervals did you use to fix this issue? 
Were you able to set both daily distance and steps accurately in all android devices using only DELTA and without using CUMULATIVE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the sampling rate to be different for both the **findFitnessDataSources** methods in the calling function might resolve this.